# Powershell v4 script doesn't fire as exe (via PS2EXE) to reset sessions

Tags: session, powershell

I'm trying to write a simple script to allow staff to reset Citrix sessions on machines where they are not local admins. The following works perfectly as a .ps1. But it doesn't reset the session when converted to an .exe with PS2EXE, and run.

The thought behind using the .exe is I can obscure the password for the service account it needs to run the command under (it's a local admin on the Citrix servers). Yes, I'm aware of the risk, and that the .ps1 can be reasonably easily extracted from the .exe. I'm sure we can do this in GP, but I'd like to do with this approach.

So, why wouldn't the below reset the session when run as an .exe? (I've tried hard-coding in values for server and session, so I think it might be a credential issue, not a variable or ScriptBlock issue.)

```
$strScriptUser = "DOMAIN/svcacct"
$strPass = "password"
$PSS = ConvertTo-SecureString $strPass -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object system.management.automation.PSCredential
$strScriptUser,$PSS
$server = Read-Host 'Which Citrix server?'
$sid = Read-Host 'What session number to reset? (be very careful!)'
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
reset session $using:sid /server $using:server > /temp2/result.txt
} -Credential $cred
```

Comment: Maybe it is exiting before the job has finished or chance to run? Perhaps block as long as the job is done? Alternatively, dump out the powershell version that is being used in PS2EXE, it might be different. You could try and run your ps2exe as administrator. Also, dump out get-executionpolicy. You shohuld also dump out all the variables that you assume exist. You should also get APIMonitor.

Comment: +1 to @Erti-Chris Eelmaa regarding execution policy as thats where my thoughts were. If you have primal script, you can compile your script into an EXE and have the exe execute with a particular user account. The security of obfuscation of the password in that method would be much more secure than having it in the actual ps1 script. I have a couple utilities for this same type of situation.

Comment: At the least I would think that you probably want to pipe your `Start-Job` command into `Wait-Job`. Not sure why you're running it as a job and not just using `Invoke-Command`. It's running locally, and resetting a Citrix session shouldn't be a terribly long process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments to the original question, I was able to get this working. I think the issue was that it was exiting prematurely, before the reset had time to complete. Using `Start-Job` and `Wait-Job` seems to resovle this.

Here's the final working version. I added in a session listing and some navigation.I'm sure there are more elegant ways, but this works on my end. Let me know if any sins are too egregious to overlook.

```
$strPass = "password"
$PSS = ConvertTo-SecureString $strPass -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
-argumentlist "domain\svcacct",$PSS
$sid=0
Write-Host "***Session Destroyer(!) v1***"
while ($sid -eq "0" -Or $sid -eq "n" -Or $sid -eq "N") {
$server = Read-Host 'Which Citrix server? (or q to quit)'
if ($server -eq "q" -Or $server -eq "Q") {exit}
query session /server $server
$sid = Read-Host 'What session number to reset? Be very careful! `
(or q quits, n for new server)'
if ($sid -eq "q" -Or $sid -eq "Q") {exit}
 }
    $job = Start-Job -credential $credential –scriptblock {
    reset session $using:sid /server $using:server
 }
Wait-Job $job
Write-Host "Done. Check below to make sure."
query session /server $server
pause
```